# "Relationship.count" didn't change by 2. Expected: 6 Actual: 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, controller

All my tests were passing before I wrote this test - after writing  the following test it failed. normally the tests give you hints where to look to fix a test, but this only shows:

```
 FAIL["test_should_successfully_create_2_user_relationship_objects", RelationshipsControllerTest, 1.146038]
 test_should_successfully_create_2_user_relationship_objects#RelationshipsControllerTest (1.15s)
        "Relationship.count" didn't change by 2.
        Expected: 6
          Actual: 4
        test/controllers/relationships_controller_test.rb:193:in `block in <class:RelationshipsControllerTest>'

  74/74: [=====================================================================================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:01, Time: 00:00:01

Finished in 1.14952s
74 tests, 180 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

line 193 is:

```
assert_difference 'Relationship.count', 2 do
```

but I dont now know where to look to fix this. I'm fairly new to Rails and have no idea how to go about troubleshooting this one. Any hints where to look would be greatly appreciated! I'm not sure how the code flows to try and execute the test to know where to start looking.

as far as I can tell, this is the relevant code:

relationships_controller_test.rb:

```
  test "should successfully create 2 user relationship objects" do
    assert_difference 'Relationship.count', 2 do
      post :create, relationship: { followed_id: users(:firstname).name }
    end
  end
```

model/relationship.rb:

```
# makes sure 2 relationships are created otherwise none are created. 
  def self.request(user1, user2)
    transaction do
      relationship1 = create!(follower: user1, followed: user2, state: 'pending')
      relationship2 = create!(follower: user2, followed: user1, state: 'requested')

      relationship1.send_request_email
      relationship1
    end
  end
```

relationship_controller.rb:

```
def create
    if params[:relationship] && params[:relationship].has_key?(:followed_id)
      # @followed = User.find(params[:relationship][:followed_id])
      @followed = User.where(name: params[:active_relationship][:followed_id]).first
      @active_relationship = Relationship.request(current_user, @followed)
      if @active_relationship.new_record?
        flash[:danger] = "There was a problem creating that relationship request"
      else
        flash[:success] = "Friend request sent"
      end
      redirect_to followed_path(@followed)
    else
      flash[:danger] = "Friend Required"
      redirect_to users_path
    end
  end
```

fixtures/relationships.yml:

one:
  follower: firstname
  followed: firstname3

two:
  follower: firstname
  followed: firstname4

three:
  follower: firstname3
  followed: firstname

four:
  follower: firstname2
  followed: firstname

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in your controller you are referencing `params[:active_relationship]` - should this be `params[:relationship]`? If that parameter isn't supplied, It seems like the controller code would throw an error.

A good way to debug problems is to run `rails console` and attempt to mimic the behavior of the controller. This will give you more specific information about the error's location. Alternatively, you can use the `debugger` gem (or `byebug` in rails 4) to place a break point in your controller code. This will allow you to see exactly what parameters are being passed to the controller, and will also allow you step through your code one line at a time.